# Encoding error with Django models

Tags: python, django

I have two tables with utf-8 collation. 
I am using Django to fetch a row from one table and insert it to the other as follows:

```
cursor.execute("select * from Table1")
results = dictfetchall(cursor)
for row in results:
  table2_row = Table2(name=row["Name"])
  table2_row.save()
```

The problem is that I sometimes get error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 17-18: ordinal not
>   in range(128)

What is the reason for this error? Both tables use utf-8 collation.

Comment: have you written `#coding:utf-8` in the beginning?

Comment: Paste the complete trace back. Judging by the code in the question you wouldn't need `#coding:utf-8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To Do These Works:

1- Add `# encoding: UTF-8` On Top Of Your Module

2- Define Your Character Set When Create Your Database Like This Snippet:

`Create Database DB_NAME CHARACTER SET = UTF8`;

3- Try To Assign `row['name']` Like This:

`name = row['name'].encode('utf8')`